# Integration of $\int\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

Integral of $\int\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx$

This is the answer, but I'm not sure how to get to it...

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+of+(x-1)%2F((sqrt(1%2Bsqrt(1-x%5E2))))dx

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**: If you substitute $x=\sin 2\theta$, then you will get
$$\sqrt2\int \frac{(\sin 2\theta-1)\cos 2\theta}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta.$$
Note that we have to use the formula $\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$. Now, use the double angle formulas to rewrite $\sin 2\theta$ and $\cos 2\theta$, and you should be good to go. You'll get basic integrals (including $\int\sec\theta\,d\theta$).

Comment: very nice, i was writing essentially the same answer (+1)

Comment: would be interesting if there is a way which avoids trigonometry

Comment: @tired: I was about to post essentially the same solution as Kostiantyn did, using two rationalizing substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx$$
Start from substitution $t^2=1-x^2,\quad x=\sqrt{1-t^2},\quad dx=-\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$ 
$$
I=\int\frac{t(1-\sqrt{1-t^2})}{\sqrt{1+t}\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=\int\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t}\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt-\int\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t}}dt=I_1-I_2+const
$$
$I_2$ is trivial and equal to $\frac{2}{3}(t-2)\sqrt{t+1}$, $I_1 $ requires further transformation
$$
I_1=\int\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t}\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=\int\frac{t}{(1+t)\sqrt{1-t}}dt\\
I_1=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}dt-\int\frac{1}{(1+t)\sqrt{1-t}}dt
$$
First integral is trivial, second is also can be considered as a table one (alternatively use substitution $z^2=1-t$).
$$
I_1=(-2\sqrt{1-t})-\left(-\sqrt{2}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)\right)
$$
Hence,
$$
I=-2\sqrt{1-t}+\left(\sqrt{2}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{2}{3}(t-2)\sqrt{1+t}+const
$$
Or in initial variables 
$$
I=-2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\left(\sqrt{2}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{1-x^2}-2)\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}+const
$$

Comment: You need neither a table nor a trig substitution to do $I_1$. At the outset, multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1-t}$ and substitute, rationalizing again, $u^2=1-t$, and you end up with something like $\displaystyle\int\frac{u^2}{1-u^2}du$, which is easy.

Comment: @TedShifrin: edited right before you wrote, it seems like we have pretty much the same thought about this integral

Answer (score 0):

Boy can you learn alot from this question. Using a "standard technique"
one arrives at the substitution:

$$x=\frac{4s(s^2-1)}{(s^2+1)^2}$$
This will make the integral into a rational function of $s$.
This substitution is invertible via

$$s=\frac{\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1-x^2}-x^2}-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{x}$$

(and yes, there is a logic to this).

To see that the integral is rational we need that 
$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is rational. 
One can calculate that $$\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{s^4-6s^2+1}{(s^2+1)^2}$$
and that 
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}s}{s^2+1}$$

The rest is a standard substitution, to a rational function and then partial fractions can be applied. The denominator is actually quite nice, the numerator is a messy polynomial, but that is not too serious, then just substitute to get back to $x$.